# Bootstrap modal not displaying fully

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am working on a front end application here when I open a modal with

$("#bootstrap_modal").modal({show:true});

it shows the modal in the browser screen in :
[image]

the image shows the top section of my browser app window.

Updated :
[image]

Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you please provide more code and a fullscreen image

Comment: Please see [ask]. We don't debug images here. You can create a functional demo snippet using the editor.

Comment: Also, please tag your Bootstrap version.

Answer (score -1):

Without the code we just can guess.

In general you only need to require Bootstraps CSS + JS, and use the following code:

Modal:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Button to trigger the modal:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#exampleModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>
```

[Reference](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/modal/)

If this demo isn't running please check your JS Usage.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I am using the same code above but I am getting the screen black with not able to click the page also. I updated the question with Image.

Comment: Whenever I press the button to trigger the modal dialog I can see that this "<div class="modal-backdrop fade show"></div>" element is created three times and added to the body segment of html. Seems like I am doing something wrong. Any suggestions on this?

Comment: show me then code where you bind the css/js please

Comment: It's not a good idea to guess at poor quality questions, especially if you're just reproducing the official documentation. Ask for clarity with a comment.

Comment: As you can see i cant write comments yet. Furthermore there isnt a single line of code provided, so i just wanted to see if the basics work, but neither.. Wasnt on bad purpose